# User Location Strange Issue

Tags: iphone, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview, userlocation

I have all concept of Maps how it works but I am stuck in very strange issue.

As soon as open my Map Controller my default blue is visible (MKUserLocation) but when I am loading custom pins (IVMyLocation, Annotation class), default pin disappear.

I am properly managing removing of custom pins so that default pin shouldn't disappear like

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in _mapView.annotations) {

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[IVMyLocation class]])

        [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

But still my default pin is disappearing. Its only visible first time.

**NOTE: Its working fine in Xcode4 simulator its disappearing in only device**

Comment: did you found a solution? i'm having the same problem, working on simulator, but not on device.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `nil` for the `MKUserLocation` in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    // etc
```

This allows the default blue dot to show.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your  objects count. Helped for me.